# How to convert string "00:05:06,607" to DateTime?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, datetime, tryparse

```
var time = "00:05:06,607";
string pattern = "hh:mm:ss,fff";
DateTime.TryParseExact(time, pattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedTime);
```

But the `TryParseExact` function returned me `false`. I also tried `TryParse` function like:

```
DateTime.TryParse(time, out parsedTime);
```

Also returned false until I change the time to `"00:05:06.607"`. But my source date is lots of line like `"hh:mm:ss,fff"`.

Anyone can help?

This is full project on github
https://github.com/DeronLee/PhoneBook/blob/master/subtitle/MakeSubtitle.cs

Comment: let me clear you want timespan or datetime

Comment: Works on my machine [and on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2iqMSG). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Working for me as well. Try with InvariantCulture

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj what the difference? I use this one to control subtitles

Comment: @Heinzi Hi. I updated the github link. It worked on your side, right? I can't believe - -. But when I debugged this afternoon, It always return false to me

Comment: @NingchuanLi: A github link is not a [mcve]. Please read the link and create one. :-)

Comment: @Heinzi sorry. Sorry I am totally new in C#. I read it and know what is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. And it help me find out what problem I had. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source data in my file is a Chinese subtitle file. I think maybe it used Chinese comma instead comma, so that's why My code didn't work but yours.

Ok. **Finally**. Not the comma. The **space**. I have to use trim() first.
It worked fine after I add trim function

Answer (score 1):

***Try This***

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, pattern ,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks. I try to find out what the difference in this param